# Class variables not correct on page

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development

I'm trying to make some of the variables from my plugin available for an instance of the class on my page.  But it's not showing up the correct values.

Here's the relevant part of the plugin:

```
class opi{
    // version
    public $opi_version = "1.0";

    public $mg = 0;

    //constructor
    public function opi(){
        $this->__construct();
    }

    public function __construct(){
        add_action('init', array(&$this, 'o_check'));
        // ...
    }

    function o_check(){
        if (is_user_logged_in()){
            $this->mg = 4;
        }
    }
}
$opi = new opi;
```

If I put `echo $this->mg;` just before the closing brace in the `o_check()` function, then it shows `4`.  Fine.

Now if I put the following in page.php, and I'm logged into WordPress, I get the result `0`.

```
<?php $pageopi = new opi; ?>
<?php echo $pageopi->mg; ?>
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write that code

```
<?php $pageopi = new opi; ?>
// 1. object created
// 2. __construct is called
// 3. init action hook is set but is never executed so is o_check method
<?php echo $pageopi->mg; ?>
```

At this stage, `init` hook was executed long time before `$pageopi` is created actually, when page is loaded. `init` action hook is executed even before `page.php` start to execute.

**Solution:**

1. You should use the `global $opi;` object page.php instead of create new one.
2. Or create a new global object before the `init` action hook (in
   `plugins_loaded` hook) and use it on `page.php`

Comment: `$opi` isn't available on the page, which is why I created `$pageopi`.

Comment: have you tried `global $opi;` ?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you're not executing `o_check` in your `page.php`, so the value of `mg` variable stays at zero.

In your constructor you are adding an action hook, yes, but it will only kick in on the next page refresh. Consider using `do_action` as well, though I'm not sure if executing one then immediately the other will work.

Comment: Thanks.  Putting `do_action` around the function call to `o_check` on the page seems to work.

Comment: Executing 'init' action multiple times may develop new issues. because it is supposed to be only executed by [WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference). Re-executing it means re-initializing everything that bound to 'init' action.

Answer (score 0):

If you add this part:

```
<?php $pageopi = new opi; ?>
<?php echo $pageopi->mg; ?>
```

in a theme template it will initialize the object *after* the `init` hook runs and so the `o_check` method will never run. That is the problem. That is why it works if you initialize beneath the object but not if you initialize in the page template. You need to change hooks, or initialize earlier, or call `o_check` explicitly.

Initializing your object as a `global` would work.

```
class opi{
  // ...
}
global $opi;
$opi = new opi;
```

Then, in your template you could use:

```
global $opi;
echo $opi->mg;
```

Though the way you are using it a static class might as well or better. It is hard to say. I can't tell what the end purpose of the class is.

Comment: I tried several different hooks and `init` seemed okay because I need access to `is_user_logged_in`.

Comment: You missed the point. If you initialize your class in the page template, `init` has already executed thus your `o_check` method never runs.